# Bluetooth Arduino control (was Speech recognition arduino control)

Tags: bluetooth

How to I control arduino with voice. I got an Android app but it works only with Internet connectivity. So I was an Android app with works offline when I connect to my Bluetooth HC-05. Please suggest me some ideas

Comment: You again?! We aren't an Android App search engine I am afraid. Maybe you should ask somewhere more appropriate?

Comment: But with that only we control arduino ya

Comment: 99.999999999% of all android speech recognition apps use the Google Speech API. That is, by its very nature, an on-line facility. Good luck finding one that can run stand-alone on phone and is actually capable of recognising voice reliably.

Comment: The fact that, somewhere down the line, after going through a number of other bits of hardware, you may be controlling an Arduino is neither here nor there. We don't know (and we don't care) what android apps are available for voice recognition. Ask on an Android App forum, or maybe **search the play store**

Comment: By asking here you're effectively asking car mechanics about the technical aspects of the petrochemical industry.

Comment: I thought I will get the answer here.. As Android control over adruino is very command. My apology to you then

Comment: Android control may be common - speech recognition isn't and off-line speech recognition is even further from common. That is a very specific topic and as such has nothing at all to do with Arduino.

Comment: As far as the Arduino side of things, this question is effectively "Bluetooth Serial ardunino control".  Or maybe this question is intended to be "What sort of voice control apps can send strings to bluetooth".  The second question is better asked elsewhere, and also answered before any progress can be made on the first.

Answer (score 1):

You might find your answer with someone else who has done the same thing on Instructables:

[Arduino Voice recognition Via Bluetooth HC-05 - http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Voice-recognition-Via-Bluetooth-HC-05/](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Voice-recognition-Via-Bluetooth-HC-05/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You might add the bluetooth/serial parsing code from that link, and a note that it gets the serial input from the Android app AMR_Voice.

Comment: ARM app works with Internet connectivity